# Docker container rebuild inside of a project

Tags: docker, jenkins, bitbucket

I have a project with the following structure:

- docker/Dockerfile
- linux/*.xz (kernel sources)
- *.sh
- Jenkinsfile

Basically this pipeline is building a linux kernel inside of a docker container.

We are using bitbucket in combination with jenkins and artifactory for CI/CD.

Currently the building of the docker image is manual: a developr builds it locally and pushes it to artifactory.

The pipeline is only pulling prebuilt docker images for execution.

As this manual interaction is annoying this should be automated.

Typical scenario could look like this: a developer changes the Dockerfile and some other ressource.

This requires us to first rebuild the container, push it to artifactory and afterwards start the build.

Is there a straightforward way to do this using the mentioned technologies?

My approach would be (which is mainly a own implementation) to tag docker images based on their git revision.

When the above mentioned pipeline starts it queries the git-rev of the Dockerfile of the last change and tries to pull the

container. If this is possible - fine. Otherwise run a 'docker build' and push the new container. Afterwards run the kernel build inside.

Is this a proper way to do that?

Comment: Jenkins has [built-in support to build Docker images](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/).

Comment: To my understanding this has two drawbacks: 1) Builds the container on every pipeline run which seems kind of redundant and waste of time. 2) Non reproducible builds as the container can change in every run. I thought this is the main benefit of a container environment to   provide stabile conditions.

Comment: If your CI system is building it, in a consistent way, using source code checked into the repository, that should be fairly reproducible.

Comment: What I mean primarily are the tools defined in the Dockerfile. E.g. gcc, debootstrap, ... If I don't use explicite versions, these might work differently or output other binaries today than tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Possible options are below.

#### Option 1

In order to determine whether you have to build a new image, you can rely on Jenkins [Changeset](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#built-in-conditions). You can check whether the `docker/Dockerfile` file has changed from the last build, if so you can execute the build step or just skip it.

Also, when tagging the image you can create two image tags. One with the revision(Or any other unique identifier) and also replace the `latest` tag with the latest image built. This will allow you to have a simple logic in consecutive steps of the pipeline since we know that the latest build image is in the latest tag. Sample pipeline below.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('BuildImage') {
            when { changeset "**/Dockerfile" }
            steps {
                script {
                 def image = docker.build("my-image:REVISION", "docker/Dockerfile")
                 image.push() // Pushes the tagged image with revision
                 image.push('latest') // Change the tag and push
                }
            }
        }
        
        stage('Other Build') {
            steps {
                 docker.image('my-image:latest').inside {
                    // Do other stuff within the Docker image
                }
            }
        }
        
        stage('Other Build option 2') {
            agent {
                docker { image 'node:16.13.1-alpine' }
            }
            steps {
                // Do other stuff within the Docker image
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Option 2

Another option would be to always start a new Jenkins Agent/Container with your Docker file or always build the image and then execute your build commands with the container. This may be efficient if you do frequent changes to the Dockerfile. Sample pipeline below.

```
pipeline {
    agent { dockerfile { dir 'docker' } }

        stage('Other Build') {
            steps {
                // Do other stuff within the Docker image
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Option 1: This was my preferred way to do it. But I found open issues for the changeset feature which are crucial in my opinion. https://issues.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/JENKINS-60028 haven't tested it yet

Comment: Option 2: See my concerns in the comments of the original question regarding reproducible builds. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: Option 1:  If you come across any issues with changeset there are other workarounds as well. One way is to, manually process the change logs and figure out if the file changed.  Another would be to trigger the build via a webhook and process the content of webhook.

Comment: Option 2: If you do not need to use the Build base image again there is no point in stacking them up in your docker registry.  So if you are always building from the source the revision will mark the state of the source at the point building it.  The better option is to tag the source and release it. So every tag will has the Source, Docker file which is compatible with each other.